# Solve $f ' (x) + f '' (x)/2 = \sqrt f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the differential equation

$$f ' (x) + f '' (x)/2 = \sqrt {f(x)}$$

---

Edit

My efforts

Assume $f(x) = a x^2 + b x + c$.

Then we plug this into the differential equation

$2 a x + b + a = \sqrt (a x^2 + b x + c)$.

I assume that $b = 2 \sqrt a \sqrt c$ So that i can simplify the RHS.

Therefore

$2 a x + a + 2 \sqrt a \sqrt c = \sqrt a x + \sqrt c$.

When i solve this system of equations i get

$a= c = 0$
( trivial solution )

Or

$a = 1/4 $ and $c = \infty $

A pretty useless result.
( if $ a = 1/4 $ then $a + \sqrt c = \sqrt c $ hence the weird result ).

This attempt was not succesful.

Comment: What are ur efforts?

Comment: You could try an inverse supstitution.

Comment: I showed my unfruitful effort in the edit.  Also i do not know how to solve it with An inverse substitution.

Comment: your function needs to be completely non-negative in it's entire domain, otherwise, the square root would create an absolute value, preventing you from reaching a valid solution.

Comment: True @Jack Lam.  Although i wonder about writing $\sqrt | f(x) |$.

Comment: that would not improve your situation in the slightest.

Comment: Put $f=g^2$ .But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Since the solution is close to x^2 / 4 , i consider (f - x^2/4)' + (f - x^2/4) '' /2 = sqrt f - x^2/4 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should already know from [my answer to your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1524921/73025) that the equation that does not contain independent variable admits a reduction of order. So once again, setting $\frac{df}{dx}=s$, $f=t$, we get $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=\frac{ds}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}=s\frac{ds}{dt}$ and the equation becomes
$$\frac12 s\frac{ds}{dt}+s=\sqrt t$$
Further substitution $s=1/u$ gives
$$\frac{du}{dt}=2u^2\left(1-\sqrt t\, u\right).$$
This is a particular case of [Abel's equation of the first kind](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor%2FAbel). You can try to compute Abel's invariant with the hope to proceed by Chini method, although this does not seem promising. There are many papers on the web claiming having solved general Abel equation but none of them look serious to me.

Comment: Thank you. Im not familiar with the Chini method. I am also intrested in those general Abel equation solutions , Maybe a link ? Or should i just google it. I assume there is no closed form. I think I can improve / add An answer of my own now. Need Some work though. +1. I hesitate to accept because 1) there might be other answers soon. There are no closed forms nor asymptotics in your answer. It is not even certain this " reduction actually reduces " ; it could be considered An equivalent statement perhaps. But thank you very much anyway.

Comment: Also , how many solutions exist ?

Comment: @mick the link I gave in the answer contains some information and further references.

Comment: Yes i have seen it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=\dfrac{df}{dx}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2}=\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{du}{df}\dfrac{df}{dx}=u\dfrac{du}{df}$

$\therefore\dfrac{u}{2}\dfrac{du}{df}+u=\sqrt f$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $u=-2v$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{df}=-2\dfrac{dv}{df}$

$\therefore2v\dfrac{dv}{df}-2v=\sqrt f$

$v\dfrac{dv}{df}-v=\dfrac{\sqrt f}{2}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf or in http://www.iaeng.org/IJAM/issues_v43/issue_3/IJAM_43_3_01.pdf